# How do you delay video playback relative to audio transmitted via bluetooth from Mac to sync with audio played via a BT speaker?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, video, streaming

When connecting either my iPhone or my Mac to my car as a bluetooth speaker to watch movies when I'm charging the car, the audio is delayed somewhere between 525 to 575 ms. It is an easy fix when I have something I can play via VLC player. However, many thing you watch streaming or want to watch Netflix, they won't work because the audio delay as it is well-made to look like make the whole thing unenjoyable.

I was wondering if I could somehow delay video play back about 550 ms (anything less could also be better than nothing!) while allowing the audio to play as is being streamed.

My research so far lead to no avail.